# Almost desperate... I'm trying to Dual Boot Win10 and Ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, windows-10, bios

I have Windows 10, created a new Ext3 partition and installed Ubuntu.
The laptop always boots up with Win10.
I tried to google it without any success.

What I did try so far:

- My secured boot state - unsupported
- My BIOS mode - Legacy
- I tried to install GRUB2, added new OS (not sure i did it as i should), but still the laptop always boots up with Win10. I tried to set Ubuntu as default OS but without any change. It doesn't even ask what OS to load after a reboot.
- I tried to burn REFIND on USB flash drive, but when I tried to boot from it, I got an

  > operating system not found

  error. 
  Maybe it is because I am in BIOS mode. In the user guide they mentioned

  > but this version can't be launched with BIOS-mode boot loaders

I would appreciate any of your help very much!

Comment: You probably installed Grub in the partition-boot-record of the Ubuntu-partition. But Grub should be installed in the master-boot-record(first sector of hard-drive,doesn't belong to a partition). Seems that the Windows-boot-loader still resides in the MBR. Reinstall and when installer asks where to install Grub answer is `sda`(If you have more then one hard-drive choose correct drive, but don't choose a partition like sdaX, X=number)

Comment: What brand/model system? UEFI & BIOS are not compatible. You really need Ubuntu in UEFI boot mode. Better to use the normal default of ext4, not old ext3. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI & http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-10-with-uefi

Comment: thanks Manoj- my win10 uses BIOS and not UEFI.
so i assume that i need to make sure Ubuntu is installed in BIOS.
how can i check that when i can't boot up the laptop with Ubuntu?

I re-install Grub and didnt have any other option for target drive (to install) other then C,
"But Grub should be installed in the master-boot-record(first sector of hard-drive,doesn't belong to a partition)"
How can i install it on master-boot-record?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. Although, it was a .iso file, it ended up being that my boot disc was not not recognized as a bootable device.

Download Ubuntu for free from the Ubuntu website and leave in your downloads folder for now. Version 16.04.1 is the most up-to-date option right now. There is a higher version number available but it has limited support.

Download rufus on your Windows and plug in a thumb drive. The drive will be erased so make sure you don't have anything on there that you can't afford to lose. After starting rufus, the following parameters should look like:

Device:            (thumb drive location) ->  for example: sandisk(E:)

Partition...type:  MBR partition scheme for BIOS or UEFI computers

File System:       FAT32

Cluster Size:      4096

New Volume Label:  (any name will do)   for example: Ubuntu

Format Options:

(UNCHECK) Check Device for bad blocks

(CHECK) Quick format

(CHECK) Create a bootable disk using ISO Image --> Click CD image and choose OS

(CHECK) Create Extended label and icon files

---

To clarify, the CD image mentioned above is going to be your .iso file which you just downloaded from Ubuntu

For example: ubuntu-16.04.1-desktop-i386.iso

Click start and give it a few minutes. After it is done, you will not get any notification but the progress bar will be full.

After it is done close it and restart your computer.

You will also need to change your boot options inside setup by pressing F2 at startup, if you haven't already. Set the priority to the thumb drive. Note, the drive will have to be plugged in.

It should now boot up into the Ubuntu install options. You will have two options: Install over existing OS or install parallel. There is also a third option, but I forget what it was. You want the parallel option. It may say something like "install next to" or something, but you should know which option to choose.

I hope this works for you!!!!

-Jason.EE.CpE

Comment: thanks Jason!
I already followed this procedure except one different.
"You will have two options:Install over existing OS or install parallel"
i dont have the parallel option.
Instead, i used the "something else" option.
is it mandatory to use the parallel option?
if yes, do you have an how to use that option?
In order to be able to choose what OS to load after reboot, will it be enough or i should follow another procedure? This is the procedure i  followed, please take a look there is no parallel option :-( https://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-ubuntu-desktop

Comment: all works fine! I re-installed Ubuntu but this time i set the boot loader to be installed on /dev/sda.  it would be better to be clarified during installation process. thanks fellows!!!!